# Correct tracked camera orientation

Tags: tracking

I have been playing around with camera tracking and I'm happy enough with the tracking and alignment of the markers with the footage when viewed through the camera.

[image]

The problem is, when I am not looking through the camera I can see that the grid isn't aligned to the camera.

[image]

How do you correctly align the grid to this tracked camera? I have set a floor and two points for scale, also clicked setup tracking scene, but this just added cube and plane which were on the grid.

Comment: Your markers are all on the same plane (the ground), so the solver will have a hard time figuring out the camera motion accurately. This could be causing your alignment problems as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree, If you place 10 coins on a white table you will find that auto tracking alone will do an amazing job and get all the orientation spot on, I can demonstrate this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If all your trackers are the floor use the "set X axis" and "set Y axis" and redo "setup tracking scene".

It would be better if you had a few trackers on the wall or fence and you'd set those as "wall" in the orientation tab.

[image]

**You can manually re-orient your solved scene** in the 3D viewport by rotating  the camera. Just select the camera rotate it about 90 degrees on X. The trackers are parented to the camera, so they will follow all movement.

[image]

If you have a good camera solve (with errors under 0.3) it shouldn't be difficult to line all of your tracker marks at 0 on the z axis on a side or front view as they should be in one plane.

In this example the camera is solved but nor oriented correctly:

[image]

Manually rotating the camera to bring the right orientation (note the tracking points at the side view at the bottom, those are trackers placed on the ground):

[image]

Bringing the camera down to make the trackers on the ground be roughly at 0 on the Z axis:

[image]

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I had set a floor and the scale, rotating the camera still doesn't yield good results. Also in the past using my own tracking markers on a table, I've had excellent results using only one plane. I just seem to have problems when picking tracking markers from features in the footage.

Comment: did you set markers as x and y?

Comment: Yes first I set an origin, then one marker for Set X Axis and one marker for Set Y Axis. I guess I'll just need to experiment with different footage

Comment: what's your solve error value?

Comment: Solve error 0.7943, I've also added a wall as suggested but it's still not orienting well. I'm really happy with the tracking and markers, I just want the grid to match my floor so I can start adding objects.

Comment: OK its much better now, seems that after doing it all again and just setting Y Axis instead of X and Y orients the camera correctly