# How can I identify the trackers when reconstructing a scene

Tags: tracking

I have made a scene in Blender but I have a hard time reconstructing it. I have a solve error of 0.2 which I know is really good but when I decide to set the floor it looks like this.
[image]

How do I properly know which of my trackers should be reconstructed into what?

Here is the blend file:

[image]

Comment: Please make your question titles specific to what you are asking, not just the general topic.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10698/correct-tracked-camera-orientation/10708#10708

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name the trackers on the movie clip editor.

[image]

Then enable 3D marker names on the 3D viewport.

Set the view to camera and load the tracked video clip as background image. It will all make sense then.

[image]