# Tracking scene moves markers from points in 3D view

Tags: tracking

I tracked a scene, solved it, and used a Refine Solution Addon to better my track, and got a solve error of .0018. I set the video as the background and set up the tracking scene by clicking the buttons. I began to notice on the 3D view, the markers are not on the tracks. As well, I set the floor to three points on the table top, and in the final render, the cube added appears to be floating. I'm not to sure why it's off. Is there a way to fix this, so the markers are on the tracks, and the box does not float?

The markers are parented with the camera, and so they won't get positioned correctly if I move the camera to a certain spot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you change lens focus or other camera settings after solving? Also there is "render distortion" checkbox in background image settings (N-panel in 3D view)

Comment: Does your scene have the same dimensions (X, Y) as the input footage?

Comment: If the trackers are not lining up with the surface of the desk you can change the alignment manually. (see: [Correct tracked camera orientation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10698/correct-tracked-camera-orientation/10708#10708))

Comment: The focal length is the same still, and the scene should automatically obtain the x/y as the footage, with the set up tracking scene? And the tracks move with the camera, as the footage stays in the same position, so rotating the markers/camera doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Akados posting the file is of limited use if you don't make your video available as well. The video file does not get saved as part of the .blend file, so there is no real way to evaluate your scene and settings. Again. If you really want help make the elements, along with blend file, available in a site where they can be easily downloaded.