# How do I motion track a camera when the scene contains more than one camera?

Tags: camera, tracking

I'm recreating my house and garden in Blender and as part of the process I'm taking photos from several angels and then motion track them. I've done this on several locations around the property.

As part of a non destructive workflow, I don't wont to delete a camera with it's associated photos when I move on to motion track on the next camera.

How can I choose which camera gets the data from the motiontracker?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130240/camera-tracking-reference-scene-to-match-different-shots-in-a-common-space/130351#130351

Answer (score 1):

Rename the "sets" of photos, so that they are seen as a single image sequence with continuos numbering.

Track specific elements that are common in different "sets" of images.

Use "Join tracks" in places where the tracked items are not recognized, or change placement dramatically, become occluded, or re-appear.

Read the following links: [Joining 2D tracking markers with an offset](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28785/joining-2d-tracking-markers-with-an-offset) and [Motion Tracking objects that go out of frame and re-enter later](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73855/motion-tracking-objects-that-go-out-of-frame-and-re-enter-later/73868#73868)

Comment: I don't have any problems with the tracking itself. The way you describes it works like a charm. The problem is when I press solve, the solution is applied both of my cameras. Camera and Camera.001. Are there any way of leaving one of the cameras untouched and only apply the change to one of the cameras? Then, as I import another sequence of images I can track them and apply that camera motion to the other camera.

Comment: I don't see why you need more than one camera, but you might have compelling reasons beyond my understanding. There is no automatic way to correlate the information from different cameras, or at least not with the help of some clever scripting (it would be beyond what I can help with anyway), but know that matching things manually is quite simple. track elements that are known entities (the corner of a wall) an outlet, some mark on the floor, etc). Solve the cameras and create "tracks to empties", move the empties so that they match with the others from other "camera solution"

Comment: the tracking information is a constraint, so moving one element will make the other empties (and camera) follow along. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10708/92768

Comment: The most important element for this to work is that you set the scale correctly. measure the distance in the real world between some of the elements used for tracking. then use that scale for the reconstruction Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/143805/92768

Comment: I'm building a scene by taking photos from several places around the property. At the end I would like to go back to render the scene from those exact locations so I can use the render to composite with the original photo. --- The problem now, is that as soon as I try to motion-track camera number 2, all the data from camera 1 is also updated with the same data that belongs to camera 2. Now, I can't go back and render the scene from camera 1.

Answer (score 0):

This task might be not for blender. Use [meshroom](https://alicevision.org/) (or any other photogrammetry software). It will take as many cameras as you want, and create a 3d mesh (and materials) out of the many photographs. The cameras can be different kinds of cameras or different lenses too.