# How to properly solve camera motion?

Tags: animation, camera, tracking, motion-capture

I just got started messing around with motion tracking and the largest issue I seem to have is getting the tracking points to the correct location in 3D space. For example, I could get a dozen tracking points on one wall tracked for an entire shot, for which Blender will return a low error report (e.g. 0.6) after solving for camera motion. But, after I throw in the film as a background and start throwing in objects (e.g. a table that is supposed to overlay an actual table in the recording) it's obvious that the camera isn't properly tracked and although the real camera may just have some slight movement from hand instability, Blender is acting as if I'm bouncing my camera up and down at ridiculous speeds. Sometimes I can almost account for this by trying different combinations of setting points as the Wall and Floor, but since I can only set three points at once for this, all other points which may be on the wall or the floor end up being 100 meters away in 3D space (this sometimes is and isn't an exaggeration).

Is there a way to greater control tracked points after they've been added to the 3D scene? Or another solution which may help? (I also have the proper focal length and sensor size set up for my camera).

Comment: 0.6 is still too much. You should recheck your tracking points one by one untill you get an error of 0.3 or less. Read also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10698/correct-tracked-camera-orientation/10708#10708

Comment: Read also this comprehensive post on motion tracking https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking

Comment: @cegaton thanks for the links. i‘ll be sitting down to read over these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it is just best to manually rotate your camera. If your scene has straight lines, you can use an application such as fSpy(https://fspy.io/) which will tell you the proper rotation of your camera after you draw some lines.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helped with getting the correct orientation, but not with proper camera motion. someone else also suggested that I didn‘t have enough points spread out through 3D space and relied too much on a single surface - which I believe may be what cegaton was getting at.