# Why does rotating the camera mess up camera solve?

Tags: camera, tracking, scene

I am working on a project using camera tracking. I have a solve error of `0.3`, and when I set up the tracking scene, besides the fact that the camera is rotated incorrectly, everything works great. When I try to fix the camera's rotation, things get messed up.

I am wondering how I can fix this, am I doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct tracked camera orientation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10698/correct-tracked-camera-orientation)