# Floor in camera track flipped upside down

Tags: video-sequence-editor, tracking

I have a 3d camera track and I have it solved perfectly but, when I set a floor, it looks like the floor would line up perfectly except, the camera is positioned upside down. Is there a way to flip the camera over and keep the position?[image]

Comment: in the clip editor you can set origin, but also wall or floor. Or set X and Y axis. Then re-do Setup Tracking Scene.

Comment: Or you can manually re-orient the camera: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10698/correct-tracked-camera-orientation/10708#10708